# auto hot key script, 2 functions with 1 press

Tags: autohotkey

I currently have an auto clicker where when I hold the left mouse button it spam clicks at whatever speed I want. I want to add another key press to the same script.

**I want the mouse to keep spamming fast, and then I want 'e' to be spammed every 1 second while holding down the mouse 1 key**

This is my current auto clicker that works

```
F1::
Suspend Toggle
Return

~$LButton::
While GetKeyState("LButton","P"){
    Click Left   
    Sleep 5

}
return
```

I thought if I just added another line it would work, like this, but it doesnt. It makes sense in my head, but I dont know how to code :( and Ive been searching the auto hot key forums all night.

```
F1::
Suspend Toggle
Return

~$LButton::
While GetKeyState("LButton","P"){
    Click Left   
    Sleep 5
    send e
    sleep 1000
}
return
```

my goal is that I want the mouse to keep spamming fast, and then I want 'e' to be spammed every 1 second while holding down the mouse 1 key

Comment: `setTimer` might also be another way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using timers. [Timers](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) have the advantage that they don't block the current thread and thereby allow subsequent code in the same thread to be executed quasi-synchronously.

```
~$LButton::
    SetTimer, LeftClick, 50
    SetTimer, SendEKey, 1000
return

~$LButton up::
    SetTimer, LeftClick, Off
    SetTimer, SendEKey, Off
return

LeftClick:
    Click, Left
return

SendEKey:
    Send, e
return
```

One remark:

Clicking every 5ms seems a bit too much to me. Depending on your script settings, you won't reach this small delay anyway. If you're not using [SendMode Input](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm), the default [Key Delay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) will be **10ms per keypress**. Additionally, if [SetBatchLines](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetBatchLines.htm) isn't configured, your script will wait **10ms per executed line**. I recommend playing around with these parameters in order to find the **biggest possible delay** that still clicks fast enough. This will save some resources and minimize the risk of some kind of *overflow situation*.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you, and ill try to understand why this works myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run two "`Sleeps`" like that.  You will end up waiting 1 second after the `send e` before getting back to your `Click Left`.  Use a counter and some math.  And, since `5` ms may be too quick for AHK to even process, try using `20` (which may even still be too fast -- you want the biggest number that will still allow the quickest mouse clicks).

Try:

```
~$LButton::
While GetKeyState("LButton","P"){
    Click Left   
    i++
    IfEqual, i, 50
    {
        send e
        i=
    }
    Sleep 20
}
return
```

And let us know if that works for you . . .

Comment: This spams click, but E doesnt go off at all.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the `Sleep 5` being too short of a time (as mentioned above in @MCL 's answer.  I tested it using a larger interval (1000) to send a beep every second and on every 5th second (IfEqual, i, 5) to display a MsgBox.  That worked, but so does the `SetTimer` technique . . .